# Necessary to call persist()?

Tags: hibernate

`removeGroupCoordinator()` takes 2 arguments: name of user & name of group. The method removes the input user from the input group.

There's an overloaded `removeGroupCoordinator(coordinators: Set<Long>, coordinatorIdToRemove: Long, groupId: Long)` that removes a coordinator from a group via an eventual call to `coordinators.remove(coordinatorIdToRemove)`.

Is it necessary to call `persist()` before calling flush? I believe that it's not since `flush()` will sync up the database to cache, which I will have just modified with my `coordinators.removeCoordinator(...).`

```
public void removeGroupCoordinator(final long followerId, final long followingId)
{
    DomainGroup groupEntity = getDomainGroup();

    Set<Person> groupCoordinators = groupEntity.getCoordinators();

    removeGroupCoordinator(groupCoordinators, followerId, followingId);

    groupEntity.setCoordinators(groupCoordinators);

    // getEntityManager().persist(groupEntity); needed? 

    getEntityManager().flush();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the state of `groupEntity` instance passed into `persist()` . According to the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) , the semantics of the `persist(X)` is:

> - If X is a new entity, it becomes managed. The entity X will be entered into the database at or before transaction commit or as a
>     result of the flush operation.
> - If X is a preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist operation. However, the persist operation is cascaded to entities
>     referenced by X, if the relationships from X to these other entities
>     are annotated with the cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL annotation
>     element value or specified with the equivalent XML descriptor element.
> - If X is a removed entity, it becomes managed.
> - If X is a detached object, the EntityExistsException may be thrown when the persist operation is invoked, or the EntityExistsException or
>     another PersistenceException may be thrown at flush or commit time.
> - For all entities Y referenced by a relationship from X, if the relationship to Y has been annotated with the cascade element value
>     cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL, the persist operation is applied to Y.

So , I would say  `persist()` is only required in your code in the following situations:

1. `groupEntity` is the new instance that is just instantiated by the `new()`
2. `groupEntity`  has some "persist" cascade relationships and these relationships reference to some instances that are just instantiated by the `new()`

Comment: If groupEntity's class has a 'Person' field with these annotations, @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST }), then a persist() is needed for the 2nd reason you listed?

Comment: If the person field is set to a new instance ,then 2nd reason is applied. It just like  calling `em.presist(person)` due to the cascade persist setting which will insert a new person record to the DB.

Comment: However, I won't need a persist(), I believe, since I call a flush.

Page 50 of the PDF you kindly provided describes a flush() operation:

`If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database.
• For all entities Y referenced by a relationship from X, if the relationship to Y has been annotated with the cascade element value cascade=PERSIST or cas- cade=ALL, the persist operation is applied to Y.`

Comment: `persist()` has nothing to do with `flush()` . By default , `flush()` will be called automatically before the transaction commits .On the other hand , if the entity is newly created , you must call `persist()` on it . otherwise , it will not be saved into database.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. No new entities will be created, so you answered my question - no persist() is required. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory to call `persist()`. If the object is already associated with an Hibernate session every modification to that object to it will be saved. From the manual [Modifying persistent objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-modifying).

Comment: Consider this sequence of events: (1) Group gets updated by removing a coordinator (2) flush called [which, if I understand you correctly, is unnecessary] (3) A user checks how many coordinators this Group has --> question: if it takes 3 seconds from step 1 to 3, should the Group be updated with the removed coordinator?